# Show that $σ_n$ converges uniformly to $σ$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, uniform-convergence

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two points of $\mathbb{R}^2$.Let $σ_n : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}^2$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable constant speed curves with $||σ_n'(t)|| = L_n$ for all $t ∈ [0, 1]$ and $σ_n(0) = a$ and $σ_n(1) = b$ for all $n$. Suppose that $\lim_{n→∞} L_n = ||b − a||$. Show that $σ_n$ converges uniformly to $σ$, where $σ(t) = a + t(b − a)$ for $t ∈ [0, 1]$.

My Try:

Intuitively this is clear since it talks about a sequence of paths from $a$ to $b$ that converges to the straight line through $a$ and $b$.

For a rigorous proof, I wanted to show first that $σ_n'(t)$ converges uniformly. But all I have is given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $|   \;||σ_n'(t)||-||b − a||\;|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$, which does not support what I need to prove. Any suggestion please..

Comment: Since $\|\sigma'_n(t)\| =  L_n$ is constant, the uniform convergence of $\sigma_n'$ follows automatically.

Comment: If $\|\sigma_n-\sigma\|_\infty\geqslant\epsilon$ then the length of $\sigma_n([0,1])$ is at least $\sqrt{\|b-a\|^2+4\epsilon^2}$ hence $L_n\geqslant\sqrt{\|b-a\|^2+4\epsilon^2}$. Conversely, $$\|\sigma_n-\sigma\|_\infty\leqslant\tfrac12\sqrt{L_n^2-\|b-a\|^2}.$$

Comment: @HansEngler: But $L_n$ depends on $n$.

Comment: @Did: How do say that length of $\sigma_n$ is at least $\sqrt{||b-a||^2+4\epsilon^2}$?

Comment: Choose  some point $c$ at distance $\epsilon$ from $\sigma$, then the length of any curve starting at $a$, passing by $c$ and ending at $b$ is at least $|c-a|+|b-c|$, which is minimal when $c$ is equidistant from $a$ and $b$, and then equals $\sqrt{|b-a|^2+4\epsilon^2}$, qed.

Comment: Ok then how did you get the next step?

Comment: @Did The first sentence in your first comment: Not sure why you claim that.

Comment: @zhw. See my second comment.

Comment: @Did I saw it. I don't see how this is right by the argument you are giving. If $f,g$ are two curves joining $a$ and $b$ then $\|f-g\| _\infty> 0$ does not imply the ranges of the two curves are different.

Comment: @zhw. You are right, the argument in my comment shows that the range of $\sigma_n$ converges uniformly to the range of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

Main ideas: 1. Since $\sigma_n'$ is bounded, $\{\sigma_n\}$ is equicontinuous. The endpoint condition and Arzela-Ascoli shows then that there is a subsequence $\sigma_{n_k}$ that converges uniformly to some $\sigma_0(t)$ on $[0,1].$

2. If $\sigma_0(t) \not \in [a,b]$ for some $t,$ we have

$$L_{n_k} \ge |\sigma_{n_k}(t) -a| + |b - \sigma_{n_k}(t)| \to |\sigma_{0}(t) -a| + |b - \sigma_{0}(t)| > |b-a|$$

for all $k,$contradiction.

3. Thus we can write $\sigma_0(t) = a + f(t)(b-a)$ for some $f:[0,1] \to [0,1].$ Now use the fact that $|\sigma_{n_k}(t) - a| = tL_{n_k},$ for all $k,t. $ This will give $f(t) = t.$ Thus $\sigma_0$ has the desired form.
4. Verify that it's enough to have proved this for a subsequence.